# How would I calculate the distance of the margins from the hyperplane/decision boundary in non linear (rbf kernel) svm?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am working on improving a SVM algorithm that i wrote and this is where I am stuck at. I have support vectors and the dual coefficients that are generated upon training.

Now I would like to first find out the distance of the support vectors from my decision boundary/hyperplane. next I would like to find the distance of a point from the decision boundary and the distance of the point from the margin. Please help me in understanding how might I go about this with my dual coefficients and support vectors. If my understanding is wrong, please let me know that too.